# Kendo tree view, nodes collapse but never expand again

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a tree view, with `dragAndDrop` set to true. When a leaf node of the tree is converted into an internal node, by dropping some child in it, it starts to behave strangely. If I collapse this node, it won't expand again. It gets even weirder if I drop another child to it. Here is the code I used:

```
var inline = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [
        { categoryName: "Storage", subCategories: [
            { subCategoryName: "Wall Shelving" },
            { subCategoryName: "Floor Shelving" },
            { subCategoryName: "Kids Storage" }
        ] },
        { categoryName: "Lights", subCategories: [
            { subCategoryName: "Ceiling" },
            { subCategoryName: "Table" },
            { subCategoryName: "Floor" }
        ] }
    ],
    schema: {
        model: {
            children: "subCategories"
        }
    }
});
$("#label-tree").kendoTreeView({
    dragAndDrop: true,
    loadOnDemand: false,
    dataSource: inline,
    dataTextField: [ "categoryName", "subCategoryName" ]
});
```

I tried other ways of defining the datasource, but they end up the same. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Kendo UI but was solved in version 2013.1.514. Trying using:

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.514/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.514/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.514/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.514/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```